# jQuery.validate and validating by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

Is it possible to validate an entire class of elements in a form using jQuery.validate? I know that you can assign rules to elements by name, but can you select those elements by class as well? I have a form on my site that doesn't need anything except `required` rules, and it's a little clunky to have to type out EVERY single field, especially when dealing with the `messages` object!

Here's my code:

```
<div id="al_address" class="al_account-settings left">
<h2 class="gold alternate1">ADD A NEW ADDRESS</h2>
<form method="POST" action="#" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="name">* address name</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" class="al_required" name="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="first_name">* first name</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" class="al_required" name="firstName"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="last_name">* last name</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" class="al_required" name="lastName"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="address1">* street address</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" class="al_required" name="address1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="address2">address 2</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="address2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="zip">* zip</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" name="zip" class="al_required"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="city">* city</label></th>
            <td><input type="text" class="al_required" name="city"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="state">* state</label></th>
            <td>
                <select name="state" class="al_required">
                    <option value="">Select a State</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="country">* country</label></th>
            <td>
                <select name="country" class="al_required">
                    <option value="US">United States</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="al_buttons">
                <button type="reset">CANCEL</button>
                <button type="submit" class="last">ADD</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $('#al_address form').validate({
        rules: {
            name: 'required', first_name: 'required', last_name: 'required', address1: 'required', zip: 'required', city: 'required', state: 'required', country: 'required'
        },
        messages: {
            name: '- Required fields were left blank.'
        }
    });
</script>
```

As it stands, this will show the proper message for `name` but nothing else. Is it possible with jQuery.validate to just set the 'required' rule on a class, and use that class reference in `messages` to display a uniform message for required fields in the form?

Answer (score 2):

The plug in provides a method for this, see the [documentation for this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules). Then you could do:

```
$(".myClass").rules("add", {
 required:true
});
```

Find more moethods and options [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/).

Comment: i tried to do this but I got a JavaScript error! have you experienced this before? [line 806: element is not defined](http://i56.tinypic.com/11wbvpt.png)

Comment: @tubbo the variable ´element´ has not been set

Answer (score 1):

you can add **class="required"** for each control to get required field validation ie

```
<tr>
    <th><label for="name">* address name</label></th>
    <td><input type="text" class="required" name="name"></td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $('#al_address form').validate({

    });
</script>
```

Comment: this didn't seem to work for every field just so you know. this would also be a much more elegant solution if i was able to customize the message for each required field and have it only show up once (a message like "Required fields were left blank" doesn't need to show up 50 times).